# How to show the number of attempts and 1 count only for the same number that input

Tags: java, random, java.util.scanner

Help! it is guessing game and i have a problem, it need to print the number of attempts but only one count to the same number multiple time consecutively that the user input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    // TODO code application logic here

int ans,guess;
final int max = 10;


Scanner jai = new Scanner(System.in);
Random no = new Random();

int att = 0;
ans = no.nextInt(max) + 1;

while (true){
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 to 10");
    guess = jai.nextInt();
    att += 1;
    att;

if (guess == ans){
    System.out.println("You are correct, the answer is :"+ ans);
    System.out.println(att +" attempts to find the correct number!");
     System.exit(0);
}else if (guess > ans){
    System.out.println("Too Large");
}else if (guess < ans){
    System.out.println("Too Small");
```

ex:it need to count the 5 once 
Enter a number between 1 to 10
5
Too Small
Enter a number between 1 to 10
5
Too Small
Enter a number between 1 to 10
8
Too Small
Enter a number between 1 to 10
9
Too Small
Enter a number between 1 to 10
10
You are correct, the answer is :10
5 attempts to find the correct number!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem statement. Can you provide a sample use input and the result you'd like to get for it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember the last entered number and if it's the same as the new number that the user entered, then don't increment the attempt number counter.
Something like this:

```
int prevGuess = 0;

while (true){
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 to 10");
    guess = jai.nextInt();
    if (prevGuess > 0 && prevGuess == guess) {
      System.out.println("You just tried that number!");
      continue;
    }
    prevGuess = guess;
    att += 1;
    att;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage Set and it's non-duplicate values: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html.

Also it's discouraged to use system exit, better to use boolean to define when to exit while loop

So you can try like this:

```
//...
boolean correct;
Set<Integer> tries = new HashSet();
while (!correct){
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 to 10");
    guess = jai.nextInt();
    att ++;
    tries.add(guess);
    if (guess == ans){
        System.out.println("You are correct, the answer is :"+ ans);
        System.out.println(att +" attempts to find the correct number!");
        System.out.println(tries.size() +" unique tries");
        correct = true;
    }else if (guess > ans){
        System.out.println("Too Large");
    }else if (guess < ans){
        System.out.println("Too Small");
    }
```

You can also use Set to tell user if he already tried that answer, either by checking if `tries.contains(guess)` or by checking result of `add(...)` as it returns boolean

Comment: Glad to help, accept answer which resolves your query :)

Answer (score 0):

Used ArrayList `list` to hold all the tries user has made, if it contains the number it would not be counted as new attempt. Otherwise attempt will be counted and added to the `list`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int ans,guess;
    final int max = 10;


    Scanner jai = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random no = new Random();

    int att = 0;
    ans = no.nextInt(max) + 1;
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    while (true){
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 to 10");
        guess = jai.nextInt();
        if(!list.contains(guess)){
        att += 1;
        list.add(guess);
        }
        if (guess == ans){
            System.out.println("You are correct, the answer is :"+ ans);
            System.out.println(att +" attempts to find the correct number!");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if (guess > ans){
            System.out.println("Too Large");
        }else if (guess < ans){
            System.out.println("Too Small");  
        }
    }
}
```